# Drupal 7 page not showing properly in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal, cross-browser

I designed a page using Drupal 7 ( http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/ ). It looks just fine i(the way I meant it to) in Firefox anf Chrome but in Internet Explorer (testing 8.0 on WXP) it is all messed up. Now if you go onto a page with sub links, Golf e.g. ( http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/golf ) it looks all like expected in FF and Chrome but in IE, the #ContentWrapper div only starts on the bottom of my "secondnav" div. Why is this? How do I get the content up so that the top of content aligns wit the top of secondnav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the mean time I have figured out that if I add

```
width:600px;
```

to my

```
#contentWrapper{
```

style definition, the content div jumps up and its top is aligned with the top from the  secondnav but this is not what I want. I would like to keep content at 800px and have them both next to each other, any hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fifured it out. An underlying div #pageBorder had a

```
margin-left:220px
```

and that would push my content onto the next line in IE while it worked fine in FF and Chrome. Well, it's fixed now...
http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/?q=contact